# unable to install vim on docker's ubuntu container

Tags: 14.04, vim, docker

Using ubuntu 14.04 platform,
installed docker:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker --version
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
```

in docker, running ubuntu image/container

```
root@2a14c4a7b565:/# uname -a
Linux 2a14c4a7b565 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@2a14c4a7b565:/# sudo apt-get install vim
```

then it is showing logn msg

```
------
-----
---
```

finally last line like this

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.4.052-                                                                                        1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

how to fix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30859601/470749 seemed to work for me

Answer (score 13):

Run the following command inside your container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: why do I need to do `apt-get update`? to install vim?

Comment: Worked nicely on a container running on a mac OS X., thanks.